# Replacing Null Values in Columns using IronPython script in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to replace the null values in some columns in a data table with zero.

The table has a few columns I use as an index, then the rest are the columns I'm looking to change.  The names of these columns are "H." and a number or "S." and a number, so "H.10" and "S.443" for example.

I can replace the null values one at a time using Calculate and Replace and the SN() function, but I need to do this for hundreds of columns.  A IronPython script seems like the way to go to loop through the columns.

Here's what I have so far:
    from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn

```
SrcTable=Document.Data.Tables["japan"]

for column in SrcTable.Columns:
   if "H." in column.Name:
      column.AddCalculatedColumn( column.Name, SN( column, 0 )
```

I'm really unfamiliar with working with API's so I know this is shamefully wrong.

Any help is much appreciated on this!